# Youtube videos shows error Cannot Play

Tags: youtube

Since last 4 days I am not able to play any video on youtube. It shows an error "An Error Occurered. Please Try again Later" on laptop but works fine on mobile. Both have same Internet connection
I did following things:
1. Updated my Google Chrome
2. Deleted all temp, cache and cookies
3. used CCLeaner to clean whatever is left out.
4. Checked and Updated Adobe Flash (anyway it was updated)
5. Some other trouble shooting steps were also tried.
6. Tried changing video quality (downgraded)
7. Tried changing DNS of IP4

Nothing seems to be working.. rest everything is working fine except Youtube. Please do help me.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what extension you hove installed on chrome?

Answer (score 6):

look at this links: [YouTube Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/I_um4JE9LlU) and [CCM- an error occurred please try again later](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-113416-an-error-occured-please-try-again-later).I would try some of the suggestions from those forums. But if it doesn't help try using different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening www.youtube.com in a different browser, like Mozilla firefox. If it doesn't help, check if www.youtube.com is listed in the blocked website list of windows firewall. To do this, go to  C:/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/DRIVERS/ETC/HOSTS . It's a text file which contains entries of blocked websites on your local host.

If you find such a entry as 127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com youtube.com ; cut it, save the file and try accessing youtube now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have google docs, google switch, google slide extensions.. thats all I have..I tried solution given by you but did not work for me :( I dont know now what to do :(

Comment: I found the solution. My system clock was behind.. i did reset it and it worked.. Damn :)